# Does conservation of momentum mean a gyroscopic inertial thruster cannot work?

Tags: angular-momentum, energy-conservation, momentum, conservation-laws, propulsion

There is a device called the [gyroscopic inertial thruster](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=kcRo5xvEkdM).
Here is a [Wikipedia article on it](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Reactionless_drive).

I believe that this device cannot possibly work and that conservation of momentum proves that it cannot work.
Am I wrong about that?

Put another way: the device is basically just a fixed double pendulum: how could there be any net momentum change in any direction after one full circle?

Comment: This post asks two questions: 1) Is OP's correct that the gyroscopic inertial thruster cannot work because of momentum conservation? 2) What argument is there that there should be any net momentum change after a cycle of the thruster. Any attempt at answering this post should (must?) answer those two questions. This is not a question about how to convince a student of something.

Comment: @DanielSank hmm, good point. I think an edit to the question to clarify that would be appropriate, if you care to make it. (Or I could do it, but not until later)

Comment: @DavidZ I gave it a shot. I have edited this question to remove a part that was completely irrelevant to what OP is actually asking. Julian, if you want to ask a question about pedagogical strategy, please post a new question and make it clear that you're asking about pedagogy. The two questions you ask here were strictly questions about momentum conservation so I edited the post to try to make that even more clear.

Comment: If you are satisfied by one of the answers please mark it as accepted. There are two good answers here. If something is still unclear please ask via comment.

Answer (score 2):

> I was not able to convince him that this propulsion drive cannot work due to conservation of momentum. Am I wrong about that?

No, you are not wrong.
It's clear that the engine cannot work because of momentum conservation.

> It's basically just a fixed double pendulum. Why should there be any positive momentum in any direction after one full circle?

There should not.
As far as is known by physics the momentum of any closed system is conserved.

Answer (score 1):

Given the persistence of this kind of thing, maybe determining the misconceptions underlying it are not so easy to determine and resolve.

[Given that we're talking about physics students, I guess it's fair to them to sort this out rather than ignore as one might otherwise.]

For my money, I'd ask whether within each part of the mechanism Newton's Third Law is maintained.

If so, then the total force on the system is equal to the sum of the forces on the elements of the system.

But if the Third law holds, these must sum to zero, and hence there is no net force.

Comment: This answer basically says "a closed system cannot undergo a change in momentum", i.e. momentum is conserved. OP knows that, as he says in the post.

Comment: Hmm. It is clear that the OP knows this. What the OP requires is some way of justifying that to the student. To do that requires establishing agreed premises from which a logical argument will follow. I'm suggesting that the 3rd law is a sufficient premise, should the student be willing to accept that.